# How to close and app after eg. 20 minutes of its beind minimized

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is any dedicated way of setting application "timeout". Let's say that user minimizes my app - I want to close it if he don't resume it for like 20 mins. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do this for memory saving purposes or security purposes?

Comment: I need to track last time a user uses the app, and the only way I figured out was to send info to the server every time the app is opened, this ofcourse won't work if a user only minimizes the app. Is there any better idea to do it maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"user minimizes my app" means that user click "home" button, so the app is "onStop" right?

I think that when the App went to the background (onStop), you can register "AlarmManager".

And the AlarmManager will destroy your app after 20 min.

And you need to unregister the AlarmManager if the user came back to the app.

Comment: By saying "onStop" you mean an element of activity lifecycle? Or is there any "application lifecycle" and universal onStop() method which runs when it comes to minimizing app? Adding AlarmManager to onStop and onCreate in every activity doesn't sound good, or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: I think Application LifeCycle should be used in this case. Define a custom Application and use it.